# Python print module says the file name is not defined

Tags: python, print-module

Working on a Head First Python book, 2010, I've encountered an exercise where I had to print a list into a specific file, and another list into another one. Did all the code, everything works, except for the print module which says the name of the file is not defined, which is pretty weird since the solution of the exercise it's the exact same code of mine.

```
import os

man = []
other = []

try: 

    data = open('ketchup.txt')

    for each_line in data:
        try:
            (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(":", 1)
            line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
            if role == 'Man':
                man.append(line_spoken)
            elif role == 'Other Man':
                other.append(line_spoken)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.close()
except IOError:
    print("The data file is missing!")
print(man)
print(other)

try:
    out = open("man_speech.txt", "w")
    out = open("other_speech.txt", "w")
    print(man, file=man_speech)          #HERE COMES THE ERROR
    print(other, file=other_speech)

    man_speech.close()
    other_speech.close()
except IOError:
    print("File error")
```

Here is the error from the IDLE:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Monok\Desktop\HeadFirstPython\chapter3\sketch2.py", line 34, in 
>       print(man, file=man_speech)
>   NameError: name 'man_speech' is not defined

Am I doing something wrong about the syntax, or maybe I didn't get how the print module works? The book doesn't give me any clue about it. I've also checked for lot of questions here and in some other forums, but nothing seems wrong with my code, and I'm actually tilted.

Comment: `out = open("man_speech.txt", "w"); out = open("other_speech.txt", "w")` - Read that tutorial again.

Comment: What? Also, why duplicate? I spent 50 minutes looking for a similar question, and I didn't find any

Comment: You need to review how variable names work. The duplicate explains how to work with files.

Comment: I was using a book to study, so I thought I didn't need to read another tutorial, after the book's one and the Python's one...

Answer (score 2):

when you open the file here:

```
out = open("man_speech.txt", "w")
```

You are assigning the file to the `out` variable, there's no such variable called `man_speech`. That's why it raises a `NameError` and says `man_speech` is not defined.

You need to change it to

```
man_speech = open("man_speech.txt", "w")
```

The same for `other_speech`

Comment: Oh...ahahahah, ok, I get it! So whenever I need to save data to a file I need to create a variable named exactly as my file?

Comment: No. You may call them file1 and file2 but then you need to use file1 and file2 to refer to them. `file1 = open("man_speech.txt", "w")` `print(man, file=file1)` `file1.close()`

Comment: You can name the variable anything you like, as long as it makes sense to you and your colleagues, and you use the same variable name to refer to it :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the file names:

```
out = open("man_speech.txt", "w")    # Defining out instead of man_speech
out = open("other_speech.txt", "w")  # Redefining out
print(man, file=man_speech)          # Using undefined man_speech
print(other, file=other_speech)      # Using undefined other_speech
```

You don't assign the result of `open` to `man_speech` but to `out`. Hence the error message:

```
NameError: name 'man_speech' is not defined
```

The code should be

```
man_speech = open("man_speech.txt", "w")
other_speech = open("other_speech.txt", "w")
print(man, file=man_speech)
print(other, file=other_speech)
```